# Firebase 2 (firebase.google.com) Push Notification - manage from outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I cant find any information about managing push notification outside the firebase.google.com GUI.

We need to send pushes dynamically, therefore we need to create script, which allows us to do this. For example right now, we are using Parse, we download Parse SDK to our server, give it keys etc., and then we can send pushes dynamically.

Is there any possibility for doing this with new Firebase SDK?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was little confusion, but as mentioned by Gerrit Hoekstra, the notifications are handled by [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (I do not know, why they have no reference from Notification topic to make it clear).

There is no SDK, however the REST API seems quite simple, you also have possibility to implement your own XMPP server for it.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not provide a REST API for their Notifications product. You'll have to use low-level Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) HTTP API [with topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) or [push tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server) directly, it's very similar to Google Cloud Messaging.

There is no way to trigger push notifications to specific users (Firebase UID), or to target properties & events like you would do with the web dashboard. You should consider 3rd party services like Parse Server, Batch.com etc. if you are looking for a higher level API, open-rate analytics etc.

Comment: The first sentence in your "push tokens" link says that `To address or "target" a downstream message, the app server sets to with the receiving client app's registration token. `, and later they desribes how iOS or android obtain this token and  `If you want to target single devices, or create device groups, you'll need to access this token.`

Comment: Yes, what I called push tokens are in fact registration ids/tokens, those are unique identifiers delivered either by Apple push service (APNS) or Google FCM to reach a specific app install on a device.

But this has nothing to do with the [Firebase UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#user_properties) which describes a user (platform independent) in your Firebase database.

You'll have to store those registration ids/tokens specifically in your Firebase datastore or in a separate database for FCM API usage.

Comment: Ah, yeah, thats true. The setence `There is no way to trigger push notifications to specific users` was little confusing :). We are using Parse at the moment, however it is going to end at beginning next year.

Comment: If you are looking for a good Parse alternative, we (at [Batch.com](https://batch.com)) have built an [integration with Firebase](https://batch.com/firebase), you'll be able to push a Firebase User Identifier without having to deal with registration tokens complexity.